# How to create a card (material design) by the number of records in the database

Tags: c#, database, wpf, material-design-in-xaml

I am creating a WPF application with the Material Design library. I already have an interface but I don't know how to generate a card based on the number of records in the database.

I need what would be transferred from the database: image and text into one markup and it was duplicated for all records.

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
    <hc:SearchBar
        hc:InfoElement.Placeholder="Search"
        hc:InfoElement.TitlePlacement="Left" 
        Style="{StaticResource SearchBarExtend}"
        Margin="20 0 125 20"
    />
    <materialDesign:Card Margin="20 0 125 20">
        <StackPanel>
           <TextBlock
               Text="Categories"
               FontSize="28"
               FontWeight="400"
           />
           <TextBlock
               Text="Самые распространенные и часто выбираемые архитекрурные решения зданий"
               FontSize="14"
               FontWeight="200"
               />
           
           <hc:ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" IsInertiaEnabled="True">
           <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0 20 0 0">
               <materialDesign:Card Margin="15 0 15 0 ">
               <StackPanel Height="200" Width="200">
                   <Image Source="../App_Logo.png"/>
                   <TextBlock
                       FontSize="18"
                       FontWeight="Medium"
                       Text="Test1"
                   />
                   <TextBlock
                       FontSize="15"
                       FontWeight="Regular"
                       Text="Desc "
                       />
               </StackPanel>
           </materialDesign:Card>
               <materialDesign:Card Margin="15 0 15 0 ">
               <StackPanel Height="200" Width="200">
                   <Image Source="../App_Logo.png"/>
                   <TextBlock
                       FontSize="18"
                       FontWeight="Medium"
                       Text="Test1"
                   />
                   <TextBlock
                       FontSize="15"
                       FontWeight="Regular"
                       Text="Desc "
                       />
               </StackPanel>
           </materialDesign:Card>
               <materialDesign:Card Margin="15 0 15 0 ">
               <StackPanel Height="200" Width="200">
                   <Image Source="../App_Logo.png"/>
                   <TextBlock
                       FontSize="18"
                       FontWeight="Medium"
                       Text="Test1"
                   />
                   <TextBlock
                       FontSize="15"
                       FontWeight="Regular"
                       Text="Desc "
                       />
               </StackPanel>
           </materialDesign:Card>
               <materialDesign:Card Margin="15 0 15 0 ">
               <StackPanel Height="200" Width="200">
                   <Image Source="../App_Logo.png"/>
                   <TextBlock
                       FontSize="18"
                       FontWeight="Medium"
                       Text="Test1"
                   />
                   <TextBlock
                       FontSize="15"
                       FontWeight="Regular"
                       Text="Desc "
                       />
               </StackPanel>
           </materialDesign:Card>
               <materialDesign:Card Margin="15 0 15 0 ">
               <StackPanel Height="200" Width="200">
                   <Image Source="../App_Logo.png"/>
                   <TextBlock
                       FontSize="18"
                       FontWeight="Medium"
                       Text="Test1"
                   />
                   <TextBlock
                       FontSize="15"
                       FontWeight="Regular"
                       Text="Desc "
                       />
               </StackPanel>
           </materialDesign:Card>
               <materialDesign:Card Margin="15 0 15 0 ">
               <StackPanel Height="200" Width="200">
                   <Image Source="../App_Logo.png"/>
                   <TextBlock
                       FontSize="18"
                       FontWeight="Medium"
                       Text="Test1"
                   />
                   <TextBlock
                       FontSize="15"
                       FontWeight="Regular"
                       Text="Desc "
                       />
               </StackPanel>
           </materialDesign:Card>
               
           </WrapPanel>
           </hc:ScrollViewer>
       </StackPanel>
        
    </materialDesign:Card>
</StackPanel>
```

Haven't done anything yet, I just need to learn how to make this function

Comment: you mean like .... `ItemsControl` ? (search for tutorials - first it is prolly already answered how to use it, second - it is a rather broad topic)

Comment: You could use any kind of visual list. `ItemsControl` is probably the best for your use case. If you use Items control you can set the `ItemsControl.ItemTemplate` to a `DataTemplate` that contains your card. You will also need to bind the `ItemsSource` in the items control.